# Display scrapy logs in both file and terminal

Tags: logging, scrapy, settings

I am having the following instructions in the settings.py file of my scrapy project:

```
LOG_ENABLED = True
LOG_STDOUT = True
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
LOGSTATS_INTERVAL = 300
LOG_FILE = 'log_file.txt'
```

These settings result in all the logs being written to log_file.txt. Yet, I would like to still inspect these logs in the terminal from which I am running the spider. I guess this should be a default option included somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You could also just redirect the command output to a file while displaying it, e.g. `scrapy crawl myspider |& tee log_file.txt`